# Need help building budget video editing PC/Laptop in ₹60-70K

Tags: video-editing

I am a IT professional, recently got into learning Video Editing for YouTube content creation. Currently I have tested few video editing tools on a laptop with below specs and the render times were devastating and frustrating. I created a sample 2 min project in After Effects and the render time was 8 hours with below specs.

```
Dell 3542
Intel Core i5 4210U
8.00GB Single-Channel DDR3 @ 798MHz
Intel HD Graphics Family (Dell)
2047MB NVIDIA GeForce 820M (Dell)
232GB Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB (SSD)
```

It got me thinking, what's the best PC I can build or Laptop I can purchase within ₹60-70K that would significantly reduce these render times and motivate me in using such powerful application? Even the Apple recommendation would do to if in the mentioned budget as I am open to other applications as well such as Final Cut Pro X.

Note: I plan to editing and creating content in 1080p, not more than that for now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify the price? I assume you mean ₹60,000, since $60,000 wouldn't be budget by any standard. Is that right?

Comment: Yes Obie, its ₹. Sorry I missed that. And thanks for the elaborated answer. It helped a lot!

Comment: @Obie2.0 Actually also I thought of going for Macbook as I saw on YouTube that Mac integration with their own application Final Cut Pro X is significantly faster than a windows machine running 3rd party apps like Adobe Premiere Pro. A Mac running Final Cut Pro X saves about 70% render time. The problem is that I could only afford a Macbook Air. Would Macbook Air be a good option?

If not, as you suggested, I will go for a desktop.

Comment: That's probably true, that Macs save time. Macbook Air probably wouldn't be enough. However, you can grab a used MacBook Pro with high specs from eBay for about 1049 USD plus shipping. Also, I forgot to consider monitor pricing. Do you already have a monitor?

Comment: Yes I do have a monitor already. I had a old desktop that is completely working. I will see what all can be reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For budget, don't go with a laptop unless portability is essential for you. Although the performance gap between laptops and desktops has shrunk with recent CPU and especially GPU series, a laptop capable of good video editing will still cost a lot.

I'm assuming that you're looking for something under ₹70,000 (1029 USD).

For price, I'd highly recommend building your own desktop. You'll probably save a few hundred US dollar in labor right there—not so relevant for multi-thousand dollar machines, maybe, but for a budget device it's OK.

The [recommended requirements](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/system-requirements.html) for After Effects are modest, simply a multicore CPU and 16 GB RAM. To get good performance, you'll probably need a little more than that. I'd recommend an i7 CPU (or the AMD equivalent).

- If you step back a generation, you should be able to grab one of the best Intel CPUs of its generation, the i7-7700k, for about $250 used or even new. For example, [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Intel-7th-Gen-Intel-Core-Desktop-Processor-i7-7700K-Unlocked-New-BX80677I77700K/123142256630?epid=11019364663&hash=item1cabd9b7f6:g:cUcAAOSwHf5a~4U2).
- For RAM, I'd go with 16 GB of DDR4, which should be [around $150.](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.X16%20GB%20ddr4.TRS0&_nkw=16%20GB%20ddr4&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=500%20gb%20ssd)
- For your GPU, try getting a [used 1060](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.X1060%20gpu%20used.TRS2&_nkw=1060%20gpu%20used&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_osacat=0&_odkw=1060%20gpu%20new&LH_TitleDesc=0) for about $200. Depending on what you're doing in After Effects, a GPU could be essential or barely necessary, but CPU is usually a lot more important, so this is a compromise.
- For the motherboard, you might as well get an H370. Motherboards are cheap to begin with, and anything lower will set future upgrades back unnecessarily. For example, [here](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813119072) for $132.
- For hard drives, I'd get one fast working SSD and one large HDD for storage. You can get a  2 TB  HDD (7200 RPM) for [about $50](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Hitachi-Ultrastar-2TB-64MB-7200RPM-3-5-Enterprise-SATA-6-0Gb-s-Hard-Drive/161193823310?hash=item2587e68c4e:g:-GIAAOxydlFSzhG~:sc:USPSPriority!63130!US!-1), and a 500 GB SSD [for only $150 or so.](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2047675.m570.l1313.TR12.TRC2.A0.H0.X500%20gb%20ssd.TRS0&_nkw=500%20gb%20ssd&_sacat=0)
- You can probably grab a budget case for about $70.

This totals about $1050 for a mostly new system. It should be very much capable of dealing with After Effects. It's slightly over your maximum (and I haven't included fans, power supply, etc.) but you can slice a little off by getting a lower tier motherboard (save $70), or a 250 GB SSD (save $70), or by getting the RAM used. Using a 6700k (two generations older, but similar speeds and can be overclocked anyway) could also save you a little.

I won't talk about fans, etc., since they'll contribute relatively little to the price.

If you really need a mobile system, it's going to be much harder to find a good one. There are a few good options, though, such as the [Acer Aspire VX 15.](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Acer-Aspire-VX-15-Gaming-Laptop-VX5-591G-75RM-1050-Ti-16GB-256GB-SSD-i7-PC/112953661098?hash=item1a4c9016aa:g:Bi0AAOSwH~ta24CO) This has a 1050 Ti GPU, about 16 GB of RAM, and a 7th-generation i7 CPU. Storage is minimal, though, so you'll end up needed an external hard drive, and as a laptop its performance will certainly be lower than than a desktop of similar price.

Comment: Would these fit in the Node 202 case?

Comment: @Zushauque - Not sure.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up getting a Silverstone RVZ02, slightly bigger but works. Thanks a lot :)